# iPhone Storyboard Editing a table view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard

I've been trying to learn the new Storyboard feature in Xcode and I've run into a problem with trying to set a UITableView to edit mode.

So far my storyboard looks like this:

NavigationController -> UIViewController (subclass with tableview property)

I added a Navigation Item and a Bar Button item to the view controller scene, so I do see an edit button. It didn't do anything automagically, so I tried linking it's selector to the setEditing method of the tableview delegate. This did put it into editing mode. However, the edit button did not change to a "Done" button and so there is no way to get out of editing mode.

Do I have to create another Navigation item for the Done button? How do I connect it so that it appears at the right time and works correctly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just started using Storyboards, so I also wanted to use the Storyboard to add my Edit button.  It is annoying to have taken the time to learn how to use a new tool but find you need a roll of duct tape to patch up the holes.

You can get it to work, but need to add a Custom button.  In the Attributes inspector make sure the Identifier is Custom and the title is Edit.

Then add something like this in your .m

```
- (IBAction)setEditMode:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    if (self.editing) {
        sender.title = @"Edit";
        [super setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    } else {
        sender.title = @"Done";
        [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    } 
}
```

Have your Custom Edit button call the setEditMode method.

Can only hope they will fix the implementation of the Edit button in the Storyboard editor in the future.

Comment: 6 years later... It still hasn't been fixed.

Answer (score 27):

I think that also with Storyboard, the only way (for sure, the easiest one) to implement a working **edit/done button**, is to use the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
...
//set the edit button
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
...
```

This is the solution that Apple itself implements if you select a "Master-Detail Application" template for your project.

Probably Storyboard is still not perfect, and hopefully it will be improved from Apple in next releases...

Answer (score 6):

To summarize:

The Button, returned by `UIViewController.editButtonItem` is a special toggling button with special behavior that calls `- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated` if pressed.

The Button, returned by `UINavigationController.editButtonItem` is a simple Button, just labeled with "Edit".

The Storyboard allows to select the latter one.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the navigation controller to push to the view controller, simply set `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;`, which will put the default Edit button in the right.  If the navigation bar is not visible, call `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;`.  Those would be called in the `viewDidLoad` method, or something similar.  Then in order to get the tableView to respond to the edit call, use the following method:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
```

That should do what you want it to do.  If you have any issues, just say so and we can narrow down the details

Comment: Yeah, I know how to do it programatically, but I've been trying to accomplish it through the Storyboard UI.

Comment: It should be pretty much the same.  I've been using the Storyboard UI also (which I have to say makes life a lot easier) and have had to do similar things and that is how I went about it. I have noticed that sometimes you have to go through `self.parentViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = yourButton;` at times in order to get the desired view in your heirarchy.  But the rest should stay the same as before so long as your tableView is linked to the viewController as an IBOutlet

Comment: Is there any news about it? Been trying to figure out how to replace the one LOC with the new Storyboard feature. Just putting a button into the navigation bar and naming it "Edit" doesn't work of course. ;)

Comment: @SebastianWramba you should be able to do something like that, honestly. Just call it Edit, then assign it an IBAction method that calls `setEditing:animated:`. Personally, I just create it programmatically in the specific view controller's `viewDidLoad` method, using `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem`. That way you don't have to assign a method (`setEditing...`) since it's a standard button item.  Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: True, I guess reinventing the wheel (or in this case put the wheel somewhere else) is not a very smart move. Implementing the Edit button the old fashioned way still seems to be the best way although there are the storyboards and segues now.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @Graham answer, you might also want to change the style so you can have the "Done" button style (the blue color). Something like this:

```
- (IBAction)setEditMode:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    if (self.editing) {
        sender.title = @"Edit";
        sender.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
        [super setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    } else {
        sender.title = @"Done";
        sender.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleDone;
        [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

one can use the dumb, not working Edit button from the Storyboard editor and then programmatically replace it with the `UIViewController.editButtonItem`.

in viewDidLoad:

```
 NSMutableArray *toolbarItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.toolbarItems];

[toolbarItems replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:self.editButtonItem];

[self setToolbarItems:toolbarItems];
```

this code assumes one has added the dumb Edit button as the leftmost item on the toolbar in the Storyboard.

Comment: This is a bit hacky but it is preferable to re-implementing the edit button.

Comment: Using code to replace the button you added in Interface Builder with the button it really should be seems like a bit of a hack... but it is a shortcoming on Apple's part that forces us to do it this way. Don't get me wrong, I think this is the best solution short of Apple supporting the actual Edit button in Interface Builder.

Comment: right, but ii still do not agree on the hack term :) 

what is a "hack" anyway? for me this code is far from hack. hack would be, if that code would gain unauthorized access to data in a system or computer, but it is just regular Edit button boilerplate...

Answer (score 1):

In case that you have UIViewController and inside this you added a UITableVIew.
If you want to add an edit UIBarButton in order to interact with UITableView, try:

Add this line...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ...

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    ...
}
```

and this method

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.myListTableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if(self.myListTableView.editing) {
        NSLog(@"editMode on");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"editMode off");
    }
}
```

where

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myListTableView;
```